# how to delete all anonymous users via cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I need to delete all anonymous users in Firebase Authentication.

but I don't know how to delete all anonymous firebase user authentication using Node JS admin SDK. I have tried to read the documentation, but I just can find the trigger when user created or deleted

Comment: List all users with `listUsers` : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users ; iterate with `forEach` check their `isAnonymous` : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#isanonymous and delete with `deleteUser(uid)`

Comment: That sounds like an answer @Cherniv :)

Comment: It's not clear to me when exactly you expect to purge these anonymous users.  You can manually invoke an http function to do this, but I'm not clear what you mean when you say "I just can find the trigger when user created or deleted".  Cloud Functions provides auth triggers for when accounts are created or deleted, but these triggers won't help much to determine when all the anonymous accounts.

Comment: @DougStevenson I will make a cron job function to delete anonymous users who last signed in is more than 6 months ago. because there will be a redundant anonymous users if they decide uninstall the app and not continue to sign in using google or facebook account. because the number of anonymous users is limited to 100 milions user (even though maybe I will never hit that limit)

Comment: OK, perhaps you should edit the question to state your plan, and also what specific problem you're running into with the solution.

Comment: I have a slightly different case than this, but I use async await to delete anonymous users that signed in last six month ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837805/9101876