# How to delete firebase auth users that have not recently signed in?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

We have an app with ~50K users and we would like to delete (from firebase auth) everyone who hasn't signed in since January 1st, 2023.

Using cloud functions, I can successfully delete any specific user. However, I can't figure out how to access lastSignInTime.

This is the code so far, but I can't isolate SignInTime

```
exports.deleteAuthUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  admin.auth().getUser(data.uid)
  .then((userRecord) => {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    // console.log(`Successfully fetched user data: ${userRecord.toJSON()}`);
    // console.log(userRecord.metadata);
    console.log(userRecord.metadata);
    let time = userRecord.metadata.lastSignInTime.getTime()
    console.log(time)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
  });
})
```

This is userRecord.metadata { UserMetaData [ lastSignInTime: xxx ] }

[image]

Also, once I can access lastSignInTime, my plan is to covert it with getTime() and then see if it's greater than 1/1/23.getTime()

Thanks!

Comment: `metadata` always have that kind of information. You have harsh app just 2 weeks offline and account gone.

Comment: Yep. I added an image. Any idea how to access it?

Comment: Your question isn't so much about Cloud Functions as it is, presumably, using the Firebase Admin SDK on nodejs.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show the code you tried that doesn't work the way you expect.  Given what you've shown, it seems like `userRecord.metadata.lastSignInTime` would do it.  Check the API docs. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.usermetadata

Comment: I've added my code to the question. lastSignInTime is nested within an object UserMetaData. How can I access listSignInTime and then sort?

Comment: Hey Greg. The `userRecord.metadata.lastSignInTime` looks correct at first glance. Isn't it working? Any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are deleting each user individually by checking last login time.Instead you can use `admin.auth().listUsers(100)` to get the users in small chunks as doing this operation on all 50K users may hit the timeout limit of firebase functions.

My Answer is based on this [documentations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_multiple_users) there is also a section about listing users batch wise.

I have used below code to list 100 users and deleted users.Although I have tested this with less samples only, it worked.  And I will recommend you to use this in Batches. And also I used `onRequest` function here instead of `onCall`:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();
exports.deleteAuthUser = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req, res);
  admin.auth().listUsers(100)
      .then((listUsersResult) => {
        listUsersResult.users.forEach(async (userRecord) => {
          const lastSignInTime = userRecord.metadata.lastSignInTime;
          const targetDate = new Date("2023-01-17T00:00:00.000Z").getTime(); //change target date as per your needs
          const tobeCompared = new Date(lastSignInTime).getTime(); //used javascript getTime
          if (tobeCompared < targetDate) {
            await admin.auth().deleteUser(userRecord.uid)
                .then(() => {
                  console.log(`Successfully deleted user ${userRecord.uid}`);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.log(`Error deleting user ${userRecord.uid}`, error);
                });
          } else {
            console.log(`User ${userRecord.uid} 
            last signed in after January 17, 2023. Not deleting.`);
          }
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error fetching users:", error);
      });
});
```

There is also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837805/20239914) which uses a different approach.

The above code will only delete the users but not their data. To achieve that  you can use [Delete User Data](https://extensions.dev/extensions/firebase/delete-user-data) extension.  For more details on how to use it i recommend to go through the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/official/delete-user-data)

Comment: This is awesome and it works. Do you know how I could sort the results by lastSignInTime (asc) so that the list of 100 starts with the oldest users?

Comment: @GregFielding You can use something like `listUsersResult.users.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.metadata.lastSignInTime - b.metadata.lastSignInTime;
      });` to sort users in (asc). This will give you the oldest users at the beginning of the list.

Comment: Thanks for this... I've got one last issue. FB will only let you list 1000 accounts at a time. However it pulls them, I've got over 1000 that have signed in recently, so it's no longer deleting the accounts. Ideally, there would be a "startAt" so I could skip the first thousand. Any idea how to sort and view just the old accounts when i have over 1000 newer ones?

Comment: @GregFielding I don't know how to ask admin sdk to sort the users, but the ListUsersResult should return a next page token that you can pass in your next call to listUsers to check for inactive users in the next page. Resource consuming :(, but should work. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.baseauth.md#baseauthlistusers

Comment: P.S. According to the docs, the users are sorted by their uid. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users
"If no maxResults field is specified, the default 1000 users per batch is used. (...) If no pageToken is specified, the operation will list users from the beginning, ordered by uid."

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I did it, but only for anonymous users who don't have any Firestore or RevenueCat data wired up to them. (In my project, when a fully-fledged user deletes their account, there is a function wired up that is triggered and deletes their data as well. This function is not called on batch deletion that is presented here, but doesn't need to be for anonymous accounts - in my case).

So what this code does is list all the users batch by batch, in each batch get the anonymous accounts that haven't signed in for the last two weeks, and group delete them.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

const ANON_USERS_PAGE_COUNT = 1000;

exports.removeAnonymousUsers = functions.https.onCall((request) => {
    return listDeleteAllFilteredUsers();
});

const listDeleteAllFilteredUsers = (nextPageToken) => {
    // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
    admin.auth()
    .listUsers(ANON_USERS_PAGE_COUNT, nextPageToken)
    .then((listUsersResult) => {
      const filteredUsers = listUsersResult.users.filter(userRecord => isOlderThan(userRecord, 14) && isAnonymous(userRecord));
        // Batch delete all old anonymous users from this page
        batchDeleteUsers(filteredUsers);
        
        // And proceed to the next page
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
          listDeleteAllFilteredUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", "Problem when deleting users: " + error);
    });
};

const isAnonymous = (userRecord) => {
    return userRecord.providerData.length == 0;
}

const isOlderThan = (userRecord, days) => {
    const lastSignInTime = new Date(userRecord.metadata.lastSignInTime).getTime();
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    const differenceMillis = now - lastSignInTime;
    const differenceDays = differenceMillis / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    return differenceDays > days;
}

/* Remember that this is won't trigger any functions meant to be triggered by a single user delete. */
const batchDeleteUsers = (usersList) => {
    const userIds = usersList.map( userRecord => userRecord.uid);
    admin.auth()
      .deleteUsers(userIds)
      .then((deleteUsersResult) => {
          console.log(`Successfully deleted ${deleteUsersResult.successCount} users`);
          console.log(`Failed to delete ${deleteUsersResult.failureCount} users`);
          deleteUsersResult.errors.forEach((err) => {
            console.log(err.error.toJSON());
          });
          return deleteUsersResult;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", "Problem when deleting users: " + error);
      });
}
```